# Shared volume within multiple docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two containers that are using the same volume. How can I set it up so that the containers can access the volume files with the correct permissions?

The containers share the same user(you can assume that php-fpm and nginx are running as someUser), and if I ssh into the containers and add `chown -R someUser.someUser /app` everything works just fine.

I've created a volume using this command:

```
docker volume create --name app \
--opt type=none \
--opt device=/dir/to/app \
--opt o=bind
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: 3
services:
  php:
    build: ./php-fpm
  volumes:
    - app: /app
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
  volumes:
    - app: /app
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  depends_on:
    - php
  links:
    - php
volumes:
  app:
    external: true
```

nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN useradd someUser
```

php-fpm Dockerfile

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest

RUN useradd someUser
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Just create the same user with the same UID in each container, and have that user run your application/own the files/etc.  I don't see any complications there.  You say "there are no guarantees that the user executing the docker container has the same user id", but the user id of the person executing the container has no bearing on permissions or users inside the container.

Comment: @larsks So you're saying that I should change `RUN useradd someUser` to `RUN useradd someUser -u 1001` for example?

Comment: Right.  If you have two containers that are going to be accessing the same files on a shared volume, you need to ensure you are using the same UID in each one.

Comment: @larsks thanks, will give it a try